# Get captcha using Curl and send data and grab results

Tags: php, database, curl

So bascially am new to php. I want to get catpcha from a website. Then I wanna show it on my webpage and send a small post request and get the results. The site I am talking about is http://www.bollywoodmotion.com/mobile-tracker-with-name.html

I want to get the captcha from that page to my page and to enter captcha in my page and send the same as from my page. I had done this in a software using c#. I also want a web version, since I have no idea on php. Any way I tried searching and got curl is the best option for me. So can some one help me with the sample php code.

This the request doing by it.

http://www.bollywoodmotion.com/mobile-tracker-process.html

```
POST /mobile-tracker-process.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.bollywoodmotion.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://www.bollywoodmotion.com/mobile-tracker-with-name.html
Cookie: __utma=164959532.607980600.1392265746.1392293744.1392969352.5; __utmz=164959532.1392265754.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); 
PHPSESSID=t37p2pqeclbmc2tfvd8tt18qs5; __utmb=164959532.2.9.1392969356013; __utmc=164959532
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 36

num=960xxxxxx&6_letters_code=hy5xjf
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 21 Feb 2014 07:56:11 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Encoding: gzip
Set-Cookie: dle_user_id=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.bollywoodmotion.com; httponly
Set-Cookie: dle_password=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.bollywoodmotion.com; httponly
Set-Cookie: dle_hash=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; path=/; domain=.bollywoodmotion.com; httponly
Last-Modified: Mon, 16 Sep 2013 23:55:25 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=30
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: Are you trying to automatize the process of sending SMSs? If so, do bollywoodmotion owners know you will use their service with a script?

Comment: am not touching with the sms part.The link I posted above is a reverse    phone number look up just like true caller but only work for indian users.I tried to contact them, But they never replied.I Know there is some api they are using to grab results,but its somehow hidden or no one knows it.

Answer (score 9):

This was my question on SO for which i didn't get answer.However, i have the answer now.This is the perfect example that you want. I retrieved the captcha using the captcha-url in the source code of the webpage which your site also contains. Extract that image from captcha-url using between(). Then maintain the session and send the request again.The imp. part is that you have to submit the data to the URL of the form, not the page.

```
<?php

    $cookie="cookie.txt";

    function open($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.2) Gecko/20070219 Firefox/2.0.0.2');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);  
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }

    function between($string, $start, $end)
    {
        $out = explode($start, $string);

        if(isset($out[1]))
        {
            $string = explode($end, $out[1]);
            echo $string[0];
            return $string[0];
        }

        return '';
    }

    function get_captcha()
    {
        $url    = 'https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/stud_login.asp';
        $open   = open($url);
        $code   = between($open, '<img src='https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/captcha.asp', '">');
        return 'https://academics.vit.ac.in/student/captcha.asp' . $code;

    }

    function rahul()
    {
        $capth=htmlspecialchars($_POST['code']);

        echo $capth;

        $username="xyz"; 
        $password="abc"; 
        $url=url of the form in which you want to submit your data; 
        $cookie="cookie.txt";
        $veri=$capth;

        $com="Login";

        $postdata = "regno=".$username."&passwd=".$password."&vrfcd=".$veri."&submit=".$com;

        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);  // <-- add this line
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
        $result = curl_exec ($ch); 

        echo $result;  

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
    }
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <img src="<?php echo get_captcha(); ?>" border="0" /><br />
            <input type="text" name="code" value="<?= isset($_POST['code']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['code']) : '' ?>" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>

        <?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                rahul();
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```