# How to programmatically complete a CloudFlare CAPTCHA?

Tags: php, api, captcha, cloudflare

From my website I do calls to an external service API to get data. Recently, each call I do returns me a CloudFlare page that blocks me from getting the results I want.

The owner of the website told me that probably I'm getting that page for too much requests and that I just need to fill the form of the CAPTCHA in that page.

Now the problem is: how do I fill the form from my website automatically? I can just see the response page with a simple `file_get_contents`, but I can't fill the CAPTCHA with my browser, because it's not my IP that is blocked.

Here's the result of the `file_get_contents`:

[image: CloudFlare page that I get from my website]

How can I solve this? I have a shared hosting.

Comment: You are asking on how to automatically circumvent a measure that prohibits automatic requests. You should not ask "how can I fool it", you should ask yourself "why do I get it?". Read the terms of the API, check if your are allowed to use it that way. If you are, you can contact the site that provides the API. Maybe the subnet where your website is hosted is blocked due to misuse of another IP in the same subnet. There are a lot of reasons why your requests could suddenly be blocked.

Comment: As I said, I already contacted the owner of the website/API: he told me that probably I'm getting that page for too much requests and that I just have to fill the CAPTCHA to restore my reputation at CloudFlare. Link: http://forums.thetvdb.com/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=11702&sid=80d935edb9d8b3fe3a2fc2a74ef3b4da&start=20#p69941

Comment: You are getting the CAPTCHA because you're making too many requests. The solution is to make less requests.

Comment: I haven't been doing any requests for 24h+, still blocked. I'm assuming I have to fill that CAPTCHA to restore the situation.

Comment: Try running your web app on another IP (e.g. on a home connection) to see if you still get the same problem. As @Gerald says, it might be your behaviour or it might be the behaviour of another customer on the same web server IP as you.

Comment: Aha! I wonder if the "please enable cookies" has something to do with it? If you use an HTTP fetcher than has cookie support, that might fix it. As an aside: if you are scraping, do please put an appropriate delay in between fetches, so as not to pass on a large bandwidth/CPU load to the scrape target.

Comment: Seriously? You're automating something. There's a security measure in place to prevent automation. Where's the confusion? If the service provider is OK with you doing this automation, they need to provide you a way to skip the security. It's like you've been given a task to baby-sit someone's dog while the owners are on vacation. When you arrive at the house you find the door locked - so you go to the nearest public venue and ask people how to lock pick doors instead of contacting the owners for the key or other means of reaching the dog. You're not acting rationally.

Comment: Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart. To tell computers and humans apart. **To tell computers and humans apart**. You **can not** use computer to "do" this, by the very definition of the term and nature of the challenge.

Comment: CloudFlare is NOT provider of API.
Requests are blocked by CloudFlare not by service provider.
It's just for training AI for Google.

Answer (score 2):

If the site owner is fine with your making the requests to the site, you could actually ask the site owner to whitelist the IPs the calls are being made from. The site owner may have a Web Application Firewall being triggered by the requests, but they can override that behavior by whitelisting your IP(s).

Answer (score 1):

THIS IS NOT POSSIBLE, since Cloudflare does not return an API key so that the user then performs the challenge this can [verify](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) with the token obtained.

An API key could be obtained by creating a [Google reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro) project outside of CloudFlare, which is what I recommend.

[User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/693806/n-b):

> You can not use computer to "do" this, by the very definition of the
>   term and nature of the challenge.

GL

Answer (score -1):

Take a look as this [Get captcha using Curl and send data and grab results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21929295/get-captcha-using-curl-and-send-data-and-grab-results)

If you really want to be a bad boy, try Googling after something like DeathByCaptcha.