# PHP + cURL: Error: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

Tags: php, curl, captcha

I try to login to

```
https://reg.viatoll.pl/PreLogin.aspx?language=po
```

with CURL. On error I should get "Error verification code" - in Polish: "Nieprawidlowy kod weryfikacyjny" but I get

```
Error: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted. System.Web at System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) at...
```

I don't know what I do wrong. I notify that this is sth with __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTVALIDATION. If I open this page in Chrome and change sth in __VIEWSTATE or __EVENTVALIDATION before post data I get the same error.
My code below:

```
<?php

require_once('simple_html_dom.php'); // http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm     

$cookie="cookie2.txt";

$url = 'https://reg.viatoll.pl/PreLogin.aspx?language=po';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.2) Gecko/20070219 Firefox/2.0.0.2');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);  
$html = str_get_html($result); 
$vs = $html->find('#__VIEWSTATE')[0]->value;
$ev = $html->find('#__EVENTVALIDATION')[0]->value;


// sending data
$txtVerificationCode='asdasdas';
$txtUserName="UserName"; 
$txtPassword="Haselko123"; 
$url='https://reg.viatoll.pl/PreLogin.aspx?language=po';

$postdata = "__LASTFOCUS=&__EVENTTARGET=btnLogin&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=".$vs."&__EVENTVALIDATION=".$ev."&txtUserName=".$txtUserName."&txtPassword=".$txtPassword."&txtVerificationCode=".$txtVerificationCode;

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);  // <-- add this line
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo "POST: " . $postdata . "<br><br><br>";

echo $result;


?>
```

Please anybody help :)

Comment: `txtVerificationCode` is a captcha. How did you plan to bypass that with cURL?

Comment: I wanna create a site with fields: login, password and captcha. After I log in via cURL it will create session and cookies. I need this to check balance  on viatoll.pl every 5 minutes via CRON, so if it set COOKIE I don't need to log in every time. But the main problem is that I get an error but not info that CAPTCHA is wrong.

Comment: If they _wanted_ bots to be able to login, they would not have protected this with a CAPTCHA in the first place … ask them if they provide an API for what you want.

Comment: This is polish site and it works sucks. Nobody knows why they use CAPTCHA. Everybody is angry on it. Probably this site was created by student who want to show everybody that he knows everything about security and webdesigning. I don't believe that they have API. They promise to send SMS and email if balance is low, but they don't. So I would like to check it by myself.

Comment: @zgrzewka Unless you've managed to automate captcha solving, you're not going to be able to login. So there's not really any point figuring out what's wrong with the error message until then.

Comment: I don't want do automate CAPTCHA. I will show captcha on page and write it in text field and send it to my server to login via cURL. It will be sth like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21929295/get-captcha-using-curl-and-send-data-and-grab-results
But I get error message.

Comment: Ok, a did it :) I get captcha with base64_encode('$captcha'); and place it on a page. Than I log in :) It works :)